# Why is there no function Stream.flatMap()?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why is there no function `Stream.flatMap()` (without any parameters) to flatten a `Stream<Stream<T>>`?

It would simply be implemented as `Stream.flatMap(o -> o)`.

In my opinion, this is by far the most common use of [flatMap(Function mapper)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

Comment: Perhaps, only the Java SE API developers can actually answer this question. (not my downvote)

Comment: I wouldn't expect that to be particularly common, and looking through some [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava-8%5D+flatmap) [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+8+flatten+stream&oq=java+8+flatten+stream&aqs=chrome..69i57.2913j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=java+8+flatmap), I haven't seen it yet. `flatmap(o -> o.stream())` has come up, though.

Comment: How would you get that, though?  I have a hard time imagining where that would come up other than as a result of a `map`, and in that case you could just use `flatMap` instead.

Comment: I'm using Stream API pretty intensively. I think I used `flatMap` in production code more than 100 times. The most common usages are `flatMap(Arrays::stream)` or `flatMap(Collection::stream)`. I rarely need the identity argument there.

Comment: It's a pity that the question is closed as I could answer it. All the `Stream` methods are suitable for any type of stream elements. The only notable exception is `sorted()` which assumes that elements implement `Comparable`. But adding more such methods would pollute the API making it error-prone. In proposed `flatMap()` you have to assume that stream elements are streams, so you would have to do unchecked cast inside. If somebody uses it mistakenly, he will have no compilation error, but `ClassCastException` in runtime. You would see tons of questions on SO like "flatMap doesn't work, help"

Comment: @TagirValeev I agree that flatmapping a `Stream<Stream<T>>` is relatively uncommon, probably not common enough to warrant its own API. I don't think we considered adding this; this use case just wasn't on our radar. In any case the workaround of `flatMap(o -> o)` is very simple. A no-arg `flatMap()` API would add bulk to the API (requiring specification and testing) but would add very little value, that is making a relatively uncommon case slightly shorter.

Comment: @StuartMarks, I wanted to add shortcuts like `flatCollection()` (=`flatMap(Collection::stream)`) or `flatArray()`(=`flatMap(Arrays::stream)`) to my library, but found out that there's no way to do compile-time check whether current stream element type is array or collection. Thus such methods would just add the confusion and runtime errors when used mistakenly. So I dropped this idea. The same thing with `sorted()`:  it does not make compile time check whether stream elements are comparable (unlike `sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder())`). But `sorted` is forgivable as it's widely useful.

Comment: I think the comments have shown that this question is not _primarily_ opinion-based. There could be diverging opinions about the usefulness of such a method, but the issues it would arise if it existed are objective. I think it definitely deserves an answer. Should we raise this to meta?

Answer (score 13):

I would imagine because it's trivial to use

```
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
...  
streamOfStreams.flatMap(identity())
```

Comment: I think `o->o` is even easier. But still easier would be no parameter at all as I suggested.

Comment: principal-ideal-domain: might be because you would be adding a function that does not actually "increase functionality" or "become more efficient" since it would be doing `Function.identity()` behind the scenes, but increases the function count and more things to document.