# Java 8 Streams - Why can't I sum a Stream of Integers?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Given a list of Integer's: 
`List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);`

Why can't I sum them like: `numbers.stream().sum();`?

Instead I have to do this: `numbers.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).sum();`

I know that `mapToInt` produces an `IntStream`, the primitive specialization. But still I don't get it.  Why can't it sum Integers? I know that this list has Integers and the compiler should be able to do the same. After all it can now infer type parameters in lambda expressions.

OK, an Integer could be null and sum would fail. But I could take responsibility for that and filter null out:

`numbers.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).sum();`

Why can't I sum a Stream of Integers?

Comment: Because (after type erasure) it's a `List<Object>`.

Comment: The `Stream` interface defines no `sum` method because it wouldn't be applicable to all streams. The generic solution is `reduce`.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33900454/2711488).

Comment: This reminds me of [Why is there no function Stream.flatMap()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854926/why-is-there-no-function-stream-flatmap) (unfortunately closed) which wouldn't actually be possible for the same reason.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Calling `stream()` on a `List` will get you a general-purpose `Stream`, which can handle any reference type, not just numeric types.  It doesn't make sense to include a `sum` method on `Stream`, because it doesn't make sense to sum `URL`s, `Class`es, `Thread`s, or any other non-numeric reference type.

You could sum the elements by calling `reduce`:

```
numbers.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b)
```

But that would involve a lot of unboxing and boxing.  It would be best to sum them as you have it, by converting it to an `IntStream`, which operates on `int`s, and calling `sum()` (or `summaryStatistics()`, which includes count, average, max, and min along with sum).

You could even use [`IntStream.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of-int...-) and avoid boxing the values even once.

```
IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).sum()
```

Comment: Replace lambda with method reference: `numbers.stream().reduce(0, Math::addExact)` *(fails on overflow)* --- Alternatively, unbox the `Integer` value: `numbers.stream().mapToInt(Number::intValue).sum()`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest `summaryStatistics()` solely to get the sum. that should be avoided all the time and instead use `numbers.stream().mapToInt(e -> e).sum();`

Comment: @Andreas or better `numbers.stream().reduce(Math::addExact).orElse(0)`

Comment: @Eugene The `mapToInt` version is actually best, because it won't box and unbox all the intermediate sums.

Comment: @Andreas right, I was only referring to the first example, otherwise yes

Comment: @Andreas or `.collect(Collectors.summingInt(i -> i))`, which also avoid boxing operations.

Comment: @Holger Lots of ways to skin the cat :-)

Answer (score 4):

`Stream<Interger>` and `IntStream` are actually different. As `numbers.stream()` returns an object of Type `Stream` and `Stream` interface does not have any method like `sum`.  Another side `numbers.stream().mapToInt(e -> e)` returns `IntStream` which has the `sum` method.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do:

```
numbers.stream().sum();
```

because `Stream<T>` is a generic type and as far as it's concerned it's dealing with any type of object. e.g. that could be `Stream<Person>`, `Stream<Apple>` etc. hence doesn't make sense to include a `sum` method.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are asking for can not be done at all, even theoretically.

I mean `stream()` is declared on the `List` interface and it returns `Stream<E>`. *You* know that `E` is actually an `Integer`, the compiler has to *infer* that, and it's not like the compiler can change the return type when it infers the type, you are still going to get a general `Stream<E>`.

But this is even worse if I think about it more, in such a case there would have to be a `BaseStream` returned that both `Stream<String>` and `IntStream` would extend, and `sum` for a `Stream<String>` makes no sense. Later `E` type would have to be preserved at runtime, so that you know what specialization to return and this is obviously not possible (well not without a useless witness that is)

If there were a `IntsList` that a theoretical `IntsArray.asIntsList` would return, this would have been indeed possible, but what a mess this would become in such a case.

Comment: What kind of “mess” do you associate with an “`IntsList`”? Is it a bigger mess than having most of the functionality of `java.util.stream` mirrored three times (`IntStream`, `LongStream`, `DoubleStream`) and most of the functions of `java.util.function` mirrored three times (`IntBinaryOperator`, `LongBinaryOperator`, `DoubleBinaryOperator`, `IntUnaryOperator`, `LongUnaryOperator`, `DoubleUnaryOperator`, `IntPredicate`, `LongPredicate`, `DoublePredicate`)?

Comment: @Holger lots and lots of APIs should change probably? In my mind this would be a "mess", until everyone would get used to it I guess

Comment: Maybe you should improve the last section of your answer to make clear what you mean. As far as it reads now, you are talking about a hypothetical `IntsList` class with a similar API as `java.util.List`, and all it would have to do to support `stream().sum()`, is to let its `stream()` method return an `IntStream`. It’s not clear, which changes to other, existing APIs you have in mind.